# custom build for VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, compilation, projects-and-solutions

I need to compile some files in my solution with an external command line compiler, and pass it's output (cs files) to the input of the C# compiler, so it will build them into the resulting assembly. Suggest approaches to achieve this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run across this same problem before. The easist thing to do is to include the output file(s) in your project and call the generator from the pre-build event command line setting. There are many problems with this technique, it wrecks havoc on integrated source control and if your generator creates files dynamically it won't work. There are ways to get around this, compare the files from the generator before overwriting them so that only changes result in overwrites, and concat the files into a single .cs with a known name file for example. None of these are fun or satifactory IMHO.

I'd recommend if at all possible you look at using using [T4](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) for this. You don't say whether the external generator is yours or not but if it is it shouldn't be too hard to convert. It is much cleaner, clearer, and easier to maintain the T4 than an externally linked tool.

Comment: Does T4 run when compiling via MSBuild?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Project -> Settings -> Build Events -> Pre-build event to generate your CS file and then just make sure your CS file is included in your project and it should build just fine.